# Item is not added into the list (from code)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have some strange problem here. We have feature event receiver, where we are creating custom fields -> content type -> list. After that, one default item is added. On my VM it was working just fine, but after moving into pre-prod environment, we got this strange behavior with no exception or error in logs.
First thing, item was created only sometimes, with no trace what happened. Mostly it was not created. I even experienced this: when I activated feature, I went to the list and so item there, but after refresh it was gone!
We tried to put there some Thread.Sleep() cycle (while debugging, item was in **Items** collection, but **ItemsCount** property of the list was always showing 0).
Now I am out of ideas what is wrong. It's not about execution time (maybe). Looks like, for some reason, SP is killing SPItem.Update before it is created for real and we don't know why. Any help is really welcome!

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access sharepoint items from code and not have admin permissions to update/ delete them then set website website.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; property

**//Set AllowUnsafeUpdates = true to update the database / sharepoint list from code.**

```
    FormWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    NewItem.Update();

    FormWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

you code should be like this to make changes in the list.. when you adding item to list.
Use Update statement in same manner when you accessing list and updating its data.

Check whether you updating the list correctly.. There may be some SharePoint security issue.

Reference Link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/01/add-items-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-managed-code.aspx.

You can check this [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx , [link](http://moldenco.blogspot.com/2007/05/spsecurityrunwithelevatedprivileges-to.html), [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jasbro/archive/2007/12/12/spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)

you can check that what is going over there by adding your events in sharepoint.. 
Check this post and debug it..
http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.com/2011/06/adding-events-and-eventhandlers-in.html

Comment: This looked promising but didn't helped after all. "RunWithElevatedPriviliges" and "AllowUnsafeUpdates" didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

so I was finally able to find out where the problem was. After deeper study and trying that and this I found out that there was a third party feature. It was adding event to each created list and was deleting everything what wasn't consistent with CT defined by company. This is weird and I don't really understand why somebody wants this. But ok, they pay, their rules.
So if you encounter such problem, try also this possibility.
However, I also leard few things during this, e.g. if you are working with SP instances from web scope, use web scoped features, not site ones, also, SP has a nasty habit to silent som exceptions. Also, if you e.g. take instance of SPWeb from event properties, it doesn't necessarily means it is already created. It takes some time, also, Update() itself is a thing that DB has to perform. Sometimes it's better to alsways check if you really have instance and if not, threadsleep for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used .Update() method in your code??

Comment: Yes, I did, after change each SP instance (list, item etc.) Update() is called.